# Map list of functions on list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I have a problem with implementing FP (Backus) interpreter in Haskell.

FP functions look like this:

```
[+,*]:<2,3>
```

should result with

```
<+:<2,3>, *:<2,3>> ->
<5,6>
```

meaning that every function from list on left side should be performed on every every element of a list on a right side.

What I understand is that I need something similar to "map" function, but map applies one function on a list, and I need list of functions on a list of values.

Thank you in advance! :-)

EDIT:

Since I wasn't precise, here is my code that doesn't work:

```
apply :: [String] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
apply fs v = [((apply_f f x) | f <- fs | x <- v)]

apply_f :: String -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
apply_f "+" v = [(sum v)]
apply_f "*" v = [(product v)]
```

I can't figure out why... :-(

EDIT 2:

Sorry, I was too tired from working all day on this.
Problem is that I don't need second pipe, just first one:

```
apply fs v = [ apply_f f v | f <- fs ]
```

Now, everything works just fine, thank you very much! :-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
[f x | f <- [(+3),(*2)], x <- [1..2]]
```

Output:

```
[4,5,2,4]
```

EDIT:

So something like this?

```
[[f x | f <- [(+3),(*2)]] | x <- [1..2]]
[[4,2],[5,4]]
```

Comment: similar, but [ [4,5] , [2,4] ].

Comment: +1 I think you hit the correct wanted result at the end there :)

Comment: It definitely looks correct, but for some reason it doesn't work... :-( here is my code:

apply :: [String] -> [Integer] -> [String]
apply fs v = [((apply_f f x) | f <- fs | x <- v)]

apply_f :: String -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
apply_f "+" v = [(sum v)]
apply_f "*" v = [(product v)]

Comment: I posted code in original question, since it is not correctly formatted in comment... :-(

Answer (score 18):

I believe you are looking for the `zipWith` function and apply it with the function application operator `$`.

So, if you have a list of functions `funcList` and a list of values `valueList` you would call this with:

```
zipWith ($) funcList valueList
```

So, using this would be something like

```
zipWith ($) [(+ 5),(* 3)] [1,5]
```

gives you the result `[6,15]`

To get a sort of cross application you could use

```
[f a | f <- [(+5), (*3)], a <- [1,5]]
```

this gives you `[6,10,3,15]`. Not sure what you mean by the `<, do you want pairs, nested lists or what exactly do you need?

Comment: No, no not exactly what I had in mind. In FP each function on the left side is applied on EACH value of the list on the right side. So, result of that function you mentioned in FP would be:
[+5,*3]:<1,5> -> < <6,11>, <3,15> >

Comment: I see... Let me see what I can do for you :)

Comment: Sorry for "<>" confusion. That's just how FP represents lists. So, just think of it as normal "[]"

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you want:

```
import Control.Applicative
apply :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
apply fs vals = fs <*> vals
```

Of course this is just the same as the instance of `<*>` defined for lists.

Comment: Or just `apply = (<*>)` for the third line (making it obvious it's exactly the same)

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out anything from your explanation, but here is a possible code, which gives the correct answer for your example:

```
> map (uncurry foldr1) [((+), [2,3]), ((*), [2,3])]
[5,6]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's actually that you need, but

```
Prelude> [f 2 3 | f <- [(+), (*)]]
[5,6]
```

If you need lists of <2,3> pairs, you can use something like

```
Prelude> [zipWith f [2, 20] [3, 30] | f <- [(+), (*)]]
[[5,50],[6,600]]
```